# how to say this is not an SVN repository for a folder copied from SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have folders copied pasted from an SVN repository and I want those folders to be regular folders and not SVN repositories, because I already have the original svn repository and would like to treat those copied ones as regular folders.

I tried `unversion and add to ignore list` but it gives an error `could not add [folder] to the ignore list! [parent folder] is not a working copy` How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Add parent folder to repository (without sub-folders) and then add sub-folders to ignored list. Or just add parent folder to ignored list.

Comment: Thank you @peska